# Web scraping with urllib

Tags: python, urllib

Im trying to do some simple web scraping and I keep getting this error, im not sure whats wrong as I am fairly new to python

Exception: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

```
import time
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse


stock = 'a'


def finvizKeyStats(stock):
    try:
        sourceCode = urllib.request.urlopen('http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t='+stock).read()
        pbr = sourceCode.split('P/B</td><td width="8%" class="snapshot-td2" align="left"><b>')[1].split('</b></td>')[0]
        print(pbr)
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception:', e)

finvizKeyStats('a')
```

Comment: I'd seriously consider using the `requests` package. It's much more user friendly than `urllib` will ever be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to decode the binary object into a string:

```
sourceCodeString = sourceCode.decode()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly you'll have to decode the Binary object into a string**

```
sourceCodeString = sourceCode.decode()
```

I would suggest you use urllib2 and BeautifulSoup there are number of tutorials available on the internet regarding web scraping with BeautifulSoup.